# How to analyze expression of certain group of genes in certain types of cell?

Tags: rna-seq, sequence-analysis, transcriptome

I need to analyze expression of ~ 400 genes with a certain function in the embryonic stem cells. All these genes are combined into one database with RefSeq IDs. What is a recommended workflow to quantify differential expression of these genes in RNA-Seq data of cells and visualize it?

All genes for analysis concern Human E3 Ubiquitin Ligases originally located here, [hpcwebapps.cit.nih.gov/ESBL/Database/E3-ligases](https://hpcwebapps.cit.nih.gov/ESBL/Database/E3-ligases) and the updated database is here:
https://esbl.nhlbi.nih.gov/Databases/KSBP2/Targets/Lists/E3-ligases/

Comment: By database do you mean a table? Your question is a bit broad.. have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I really apologize for it being so broad because I am a very new to bioinformatics and a little bit lost. I mean all genes I need to analyze are in a database https://hpcwebapps.cit.nih.gov/ESBL/Database/E3-ligases/

Comment: Hey no problem. Ok if you have 400+ genes, and expression values, you need to have them onto a count table, where rows are genes, and columns are your samples. If you can do some basic R, then try to run DESeq (https://www.nature.com/articles/nprot.2013.099) or edgeR (https://bioinformatics-core-shared-training.github.io/cruk-bioinf-sschool/Day3/rnaSeq_DE.pdf)

Comment: You might have a look at papers such as this one: https://www.embopress.org/doi/10.15252/msb.20188746